# Missing CDC capture Job when enabling CDC on table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cdc

My database has CDC enabled and it was working fine on several tables. One day (don't know why) it stopped working: no new change was recorded.

I then proceeded to disable CDC as follows:

```
exec sys.sp_cdc_disable_db
```

I then re-enabled it as follows:

```
exec sys.sp_cdc_enable_db

GO

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  
    @source_schema = N'dbo'  
  , @source_name = N'resource'  
  , @role_name = NULL  
  , @capture_instance = N'dbo_resource'   
  , @supports_net_changes = 1     
  , @captured_column_list = N'Id,Name,Status'    
GO
```

Those commands run fine, but it doesn't solve my problem.

I have checked and see that all tables needed for CDC were created, but browsing the agent job I see only the CLEANUP jobs were created, the CAPTURE jobs are missing.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what happened to the capture job (SQL Agent jobs don't typically go missing), but here's how you can get it back.

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_add_job @job_type = N'capture';
GO
```

One thing to note is that the CDC capture agent and the replication log reader agent are the same thing. Literally. So, if someone recently added replication to your database, your capture job may have been replaced by the replication log reader job. You can see what cdc log scan sessions have been happening through the `sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions` view.

Comment: Replicate and CDC seem not  work together , I have try to remove the replicate , and then enable cdc , cdc  working fine . But now when add replicate back, Replicate not working :(( . What will I do now ?

Comment: What do you mean by "CDC is not working"? If your metric is that the CDC job isn't there, that's not the thing to be looking at. Make sure that sys.dm_cdc_log_scan_sessions is showing something recent and that should be good enough.

Comment: CDC is not working mean that no rows tracking add to the cdc table , and when check the agent job I see the capture job missing.  Adoupt replicate is the problem I delete all the subscriptions and publication ,then run script enable cdc again ,cdc working, job capture was created and tracking rows insert into the cdc table. But when create publication and subscription back ,replicate fail :( , I had disabled all replication config remove all distributed database and re-create replicate configure and publication and subscription now all cdc and replication working fine.